# php/oracle - Create a table depending upon number of columns

Tags: php, html, sql, oracle

I have a query (not showing here, because it's not the problem) that give me another query like this:

```
SELECT NAME, ID FROM TABLE1
```

or

```
SELECT USER, EMAIL, NUMBER FROM TABLE2
```

This in dependency of the number of columns from the corresponding table.

So i can use these columns for php variables ... that's perfekt.

BUT: How can i create a dynamic html table depending upon number of columns in php, because it can be 1 column or X Columns.

For my example it has to be:

```
...
<td>NAME</td>
<td>ID</td>
...
```

or

```
...
<td>USER</td>
<td>EMAIL</td>
<td>NUMBER</td>
...
```

in php for the moment my code is like this:

```
...
foreach ($rows as $value) {
        $res .= '
              <tr>
                <td>'.$value["NAME"].'</td>
                <td>'.$value["ID"].'</td>
              </tr>
              ';
        }
...
```

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution like this:

```
$ first = true;
Foreach ($row as $rows) {
    $keys = [];

    If ($first) {
Foreach( $row as  $key => $value) // dynamic table header
{
        Echo ‘<th>’.$key.’</th>’
        $keys[] = $key;
}
  $first = false;
}
…
For int (i=0;iy$keys.count();i++){ // dynamic table row
Echo ‘<tr>’.$row[keys[i]].</tr>’;
…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A example with PDO

```
 <?php
    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><th>Reg date</th></tr>";

    class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
        function __construct($it) {
            parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
        }

        function current() {
            return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
        }

        function beginChildren() {
            echo "<tr>";
        }

        function endChildren() {
            echo "</tr>" . "\n";
        }
    }

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDBPDO";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MyGuests");
        $stmt->execute();

        // set the resulting array to associative
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
            echo $v;
        }
        $dsn = null;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $conn = null;
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: oracle sql not mysql - i think, it is not the same or can i use it?

Comment: PDO should allow you to use any kind of a database, change the new PDO statement accordingly (look it up) and you should be fine.